# Is there a standard power function over IEEE 754 double precision numbers?

Tags: floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

Most languages carry in their standard library a power function. For instance, in C, "math.h" provides

```
double pow(double a, double b);
```

I'm going to assume that in practically all languages the results are approximate. That is: the result of a call to pow is not necessarily the closest double to the exact solution, nor is it a rounding of the exact version. I'm basing this assumption on the fact that doing this would require expensive interval arithmetic.

**1) Is this assumption correct?**

If it is indeed correct, maybe it doesn't matter. After all, perhaps the maximum error is known over the range of doubles... but again perhaps it's not because there are many many doubles one could test.

**2) Is an absolute (parameter independent) bound on the relative error of the pow function known**

If not... well maybe we can give up accuracy for consistency. Even if the results are approximate and the bound isn't clear, perhaps at least we can be sure that the function will always return the same result for the same input across various implementations. Maybe there's even a *standard* approximate pow function?

**3) Is there a standard power function in any language which carries a precise semantic and is guaranteed to be consistent across different library versions or compiler versions?**

Edit:
Apparently, (1) is known as the "table maker's dilemma" http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/LOG10HAF.TXT

Answer (score 0):

Different languages and frameworks provide different guarantees on the accuracy of transcendental functions, since on many platforms cases a function which produces a nearly-correct result can be much faster than one which guarantees a result that is within 0.51LSB of a correct result, and a function which is only accurate to 50 bits will often be more useful than one which takes twice as long to achieve 52-bit accuracy, especially if an application is going to toss out all but the top 15 or so bits anyhow (common in graphics code).

It's also worth noting that some languages have separate power functions for integer and floating-point exponents.  Many power functions with an integer exponent may accept negative bases without complaint, and some will unconditionally return 1 when the exponent is zero, even if the base is NaN or +/- Infinity, while power functions which accept floating-point exponents will often return NaN in the latter case.